# Get imported components programmatically

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to be able to access the root `components` objects in a component. For instance, In the following component, I import and register two child components, now how do I get the `components` property in the `mounted` hook?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SomeComponent />
    <AnotherComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import SomeComponent from '@/components/home/SomeComponent';
  import AnotherComponent from '@/components/home/AnotherComponent';

  export default {
    components: { SomeComponent, AnotherComponent }, // I need to access this from the mounted hook
    mounted() {
      console.log('registered components:', Object.keys(componentsObject))
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have tried `this.components`, but that returns `undefined`, and then I tried just logging `this` to see what's available, but there's no `components` property, or anything that resembles what I'm after, so I dunno if there's some other way I could access it?

**UPDATE:** The reason that I want to do this is that I'm essentially creating a component slideshow, so I want to do `Object.keys(components).length` to let me programmatically determine the amount of slides, without the need for a `amount` variable that I have to manually update every time I create another slide.

Comment: Could you explain why you need this? There may be some other way to achieve the thing you’re trying to do if we know what it is

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen 100%, I added the explanation to the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach to this problem. You may insert a property called `slidesData` in your `data()` method in your `parent` component.

```
data() {
  slidesData: [
    { id: 1, title: 'Sample Slide title', description: 'Lorem ipsum', ... },
    { id: 2, title: 'Sample Slide 2 title', description: 'Dolor sit amet', ... },
  ]
}
```

and with this sample data, you can create a reusable component called `SlideComponent`. You can then "v-for" the data and pass it to the `SlideComponent` and there, you can format the data to your liking.

Going back to your problem, with this approach, you don't need to access the "Slide" component itself, you just have to access the `slideData` instead. This is a "Vue way" to solve the problem.